# WPF pre-render a list w/o actually showing it

Tags: wpf, list, prerender

Is there a way to "pre-render" a list in WPF without actually showing it to the user? I have a list that renders fairly slowly ( a few seconds ) the first time it is displayed to the user.

I'd like to pre-render/pre-draw the list so that the few seconds it takes to display the list to the users is not noticeable. I'd like this to happen while the app is starting up - while my splash screen is displayed.

What is the best way to accomplish this?

EDIT:

Here is my list item style. As you can see the target type is a Button. The button also has a RoutedEvent (Command) set on it.

```
<Style x:Key="Button_ProductFinder_Item" TargetType="Button">
    <Setter Property="Control.Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">

                <Grid Width="690" Height="181"   >

                    <Image Name="Up" Source="{StaticResource Img_ProductFinder_FriendUp}" Stretch="Uniform"/>
                    <Image Name="Down" Source="{StaticResource Img_ProductFinder_FriendDn}" Visibility="Hidden" Stretch="Uniform"/>

                    <Canvas Name="Clip" ClipToBounds="True" Height="162" Width="175" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,10,0,0" >
                        <Image Name="DynamicFriend"  Stretch="UniformToFill" Canvas.Left="16" Canvas.Top="-10" HorizontalAlignment="Left"  Source="{Binding ImageSource}" Height="162" Width="162" />
                        <Canvas.RenderTransform>
                            <TransformGroup>
                                <TranslateTransform />
                            </TransformGroup>
                        </Canvas.RenderTransform>
                    </Canvas>

                    <TextBlock Name="DynamicName" Margin="210,69,0,0"  Style="{StaticResource ButtonFriend_Textstyle}"
                                   TextWrapping="Wrap" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="440" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Height="Auto" 
                                   Text="{Binding ProductName}"  />
                </Grid>

                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True">
                        <Setter TargetName="Up" Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden"/>
                        <Setter TargetName="Down" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                        <Setter TargetName="Clip" Property="RenderTransform">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <TransformGroup>
                                    <TranslateTransform Y="2"/>
                                </TransformGroup>
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                        <Setter TargetName="DynamicName" Property="RenderTransform">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <TransformGroup>
                                    <TranslateTransform Y="2"/>
                                </TransformGroup>
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                        <Setter TargetName="DynamicName" Property="Foreground" Value="#FFFFFF"/>
                        <Trigger.EnterActions>
                            <ctrls:ButtonSoundPlayerAction SoundFile="buttonclick.wav"/>
                        </Trigger.EnterActions>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Answer (score 1):

- Check WHAT is slow. Really. Itf it is like the db filling up the list, your question is totally off (as the perforamnce is not WPF realted).
- How large is the list? I have a list of 5000 elements rendering in a moments notice. Mosty because my 4.0 virtual list only renders what is on the list. You are not data bound while fillng up the list, or?
- Finally, what is slow in the rndering? Use a wpf profiler to find out and tell us - because at the nd of the day you may simply try to optimize the wrong thing.

Comment: It's definitely something in my ListViewItem style. When I strip it down to a bare minimum look it renders instantly. Unfortunately though, altering the style is not an option. The app is for one of our extremely picky clients.

Comment: The list contains only about 500 items. But the item style is very elaborate. The list is virtualized as well.

Comment: Brent are you databinding these items to CLR objects?  How elaborate is the ListViewItemStyle?  Could you post an example?

Comment: Yeah. WIthout more inforamtion it is impossible to answer.

Comment: I edited my original post to include the xaml markup for the ListItem style. It's not extremely elaborate, but its apparently enough to slow the list down significantly.

Comment: After looking at that style, I am not sure that it is the styles fault.  I have much more involved styles that do not take long to render.  Are you using an XMLDataProvider to get your XML or a homegrown solution?

Comment: It's definitely the style. If I change it to just the TextBlock that binds to ProductName it's lightning fast.

Comment: Try removing elements from the bottom up.  (e.g. Image from canvas, if that doesnt do it, then the whole canvas.  If that doesn't do it, then one or both images in the grid container.)  Eventually you may find the offending control/item and then you can try to find a way to speed it up from there.    Have you tried just having the Image that is bound to ImageSource instead of all that other stuff.  I bet that is the culprit.  If image source is different for each item, it has to access 500 or so images and load them in.  Disk access alone can take a lot of time for that.

Comment: That does seem to be the case - the DynamicFriend image. Yeah it is binding to an ImageSource object. I would think VirtualizingStackPanel would only open the visible images but apparently that is not the case.  So that brings us back to my original question - is there a way to prerender my list?  Btw - I really appreciate you taking the time to look at this.

Comment: Is your data retrieval on a separate thread from your UI?  If not (and I don't know if this will do anything) try moving it off to a BackgroundWorker.  If there is a way to move the image loading off to a background worker, then that will likely fix your problem.  It won't make it load faster, but it will let you separate your UI from your data loading, and give you a way to tell when the images are all loaded.  Otherwise, I don't know without mocking up a text myself.

Comment: The data is already loaded into an ObservableCollection when the app starts. I did manage to speed it up by not setting ImageSource on each object in the collection until the screen is displayed. Like this:

Comment: Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(((Action)(() =>
            {
               foreach(Bear bear in (ObservableCollection<Bear>)DataContext)
               {
                    bear.ImageSource = new System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage(new Uri(bear.Image));
                    bear.ImageSource.DecodePixelWidth = 50;
               }
               _productList.ItemsSource = (ObservableCollection<Bear>)DataContext;
               FlushWindowsMessageQueue();

            })), DispatcherPriority.Background);

Comment: The change above was implemented before I posted this question so it's still about 3 seconds slow. I don't think I can load the images on a seperate thread since it's part of the UI. It seems like they need to be loaded on the UI thread and that's the part thats slow.

Comment: well the image itself is just going into a property on your model right?  That can be put off on another thread, which will update the ImageSource property when it finishes loading the image.  OnPropertyChanged will notify the UI that the ImageSource has changed and the UI will update.  The UI doesn't have to handle any thing really.  Are you using the MVVM design pattern?  If not, I would suggest it, expecially in this case.

Answer (score 0):

You could always set the list (or the whole window the list is contained in) to collapsed in it's initial state, and then un-collapse it when you get word back from your data retrieval thread that it is done.

I have done that with a couple of my other programs and it works pretty well.

1. User executes the program, splash screen displays, and main window loads collapsed.
2. Data retrieval thread executes, gets data, reports it is finished.
3. Splash screen disappears, main window displays and list is populated.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. The data retrieval is very fast. The data is loaded from a local xml file. My replies to TomTom above give a bit more detail about my problem.